# Найти и заменить значение в скобках

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида:

```
String text = "(слива) какие-то другие слова [яблоко], еще слова {груша}.";
```

Нужно найти и заменить слова в скобках, не заменяя при этом сами скобки.

Если я пишу:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(\\(|\\[|\\{).*?(\\)|\\]|\\})", "фрукт");
```

то на выходе получаю:

```
фрукт какие-то другие слова фрукт, еще слова фрукт.
```

то есть скобки уходят вместе с фруктом, а нужно, чтобы они остались.

Comment: `text = text.replaceAll("(\\(|\\[|\\{).*?(\\)|\\]|\\})", "$1фрукт$2");`?

Comment: А работает? А то я с java дел не имел :) Про доллар и число в результирующей строке: это подстановка группы захвата (по номеру за долларом) из найденного совпадения, т.е. вместо `$1` должна быть подставлена подстрока найденная по шаблону `(\\(|\\[|\\{)`, а вместо `$2` - `(\\)|\\]|\\})`.

Comment: @Visman только регулярку можно упростить до `([\\[({]).*?([})\\]])`

Comment: replaceAll вторым аргументом принимает просто строку, поэтому работать не должно

Comment: https://ideone.com/lpZBJJ - обратные ссылки `$1` и `$2` подставляют значения, которые захватывают подмаски (группы) №1 и №2.

Comment: Хммм, значит я ошибся. Напишите  кто-нибудь ответ тогда?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По совету пользователя [visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083) почитал описание метода `appendReplacement` класса `Matcher`.
Туда можно провалиться, поставив `breakPoint` в методе `replaceAll` класса `String`.

> The replacement string may contain references to subsequences
>   captured during the previous match: Each occurrence of
>   **${name}** or **$g**
>   will be replaced by the result of evaluating the corresponding
>   **{#group(String)}** or **{#group(int)}**
>   respectively.

Таким образом, если написать

```
text = text.replaceAll("(\\(|\\[|\\{).*?(\\)|\\]|\\})", "$1фрукт$2");
```

первое вхождение группы `$1` будет то, что получено в результате выражения слева

```
(\\(|\\[|\\{)
```

второе вхождение группы `$2` будет то, что получено в результате выражения справа

```
(\\)|\\]|\\})
```

(то, что в круглых скобочках, грубо говоря)

**Важно:** номер присваивается каждой группе, включая вложенные. Но в моем случае их всего две.

В итоге получается

```
"(фрукт) какие-то другие слова [фрукт], еще слова {фрукт}."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "<слова> какие-то другие [слова], еще {слово}, еще очень нужное (слово)";
        String text2 = text.replaceAll("(\\(|\\[|\\{|\\<).*?(\\)|\\]|\\}|\\>)", "$1Замена$2");
        // $1 и $2 оставляет знаки <>, (), [], {}.

        System.out.println("Было:  " + text);
        System.out.println("Стало: " + text2);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]